# How do I keep previous input for a Select tag after validation fails?

Tags: php, html, validation, netbeans, html-select

this is my first post here and I might need the help I could get, please.

My problem here is, I was able to get the other fields to keep the user's previous input. However, I'm stuck to when it came to doing the same with a `select` tag in HTML.

Below is the specific code that I've got to make that `select` tag.

```
        <label>Brick Type: </label>
        <select name='type'>
            <?php
            $type = ['', "A grade Red/Cream brick $2", "B grade Red/Cream brick $1.50", "Red/Cream clinkers $2.50"];
            foreach ($type as $t){
                $select = ($t == $type) ? 'selected' : '';
                echo "<option value='$t' $select>$t</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Below here is the output for that code...\

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL6LV.png)

Then when I tried to do the same thing as what I've done with the rest by adding in that `value="<?=$type??'';?>"` within the `select` tag. Although, the output still doesn't keep the previous input that the user has entered.

```
        <label>Brick Type: </label>
        <select name='type' value="<?=$type??'';?>">
            <?php
            $type = ['', "A grade Red/Cream brick $2", "B grade Red/Cream brick $1.50", "Red/Cream clinkers $2.50"];
            foreach ($type as $t){
                $select = ($t == $type) ? 'selected' : '';
                echo "<option value='$t' $select>$t</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

If it helps, here's my complete code. I'm doing this in NetBeans and I'm still a beginner when having to deal with PHP and HTML altogether hehe

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" novalidate="true">
    <div class="box"><h1>Brick Order</h1></div>​
    <fieldset>
        <label>Customer Name:
            <span class="error">
                <?= $errors['cusName']??'';?>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type='text' name='cusName' value="<?=$cusName??'';?>"/>
        <br>
     
              
        <label>Mobile:
            <span class='error'>
                <?= $errors["mobile"]??'';?>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type='text' name='mobile' maxlength="10" value="<?=$mobile??'';?>"/>
        <br>        
        
        
        <label>Preferred delivery date:</label>
        <input type='date' name='delivery' value="<?=$date??'';?>"/>
        <br>
           
        
        <label>Number of Bricks:
            <span class='error'>
                <?= $errors["num_bricks"]??'';?>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type='number' name='num_bricks' value="<?=$num_bricks??'';?>"/>
        <br>        
  
        
        <label>Brick Type: </label>
        <select name='type' value="<?=$type??'';?>">
            <?php
            $type = ['', "A grade Red/Cream brick $2", "B grade Red/Cream brick $1.50", "Red/Cream clinkers $2.50"];
            foreach ($type as $t){
                $select = ($t == $type) ? 'selected' : '';
                echo "<option value='$t' $select>$t</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br>   
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Thank you in advanced by the way!

Comment: First code Block. First fix that issue: You can not do `$t == $type` when $type is an array at this point. Maybe rename that array you are creating there, so it does not have the same name. e.g. `$typeOptions = ['', "A grade Red/Cream brick $2",]`

Answer (score 0):

put your previous value in the else part
`$select = ($t == $type) ? 'selected' : 'your previous value';`

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better